# Android SDK - What to download?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to develop android applications, i've downloaded all the necessary.

One last question:

if i decided to create apps that are compatible with for example starting from API 11 and later, what is the **strict necessary** i need to download from Androis SDK Manager?

I need to download all?
What are Android SDK build-tools?
What are other downloads in the list?

Can someone post a screenshot of strict necessary scenario to do what i'm need?

thank you

[image]

Comment: you already have all the necessary things. when creating you're project specify 11 as minSdkVersion.

Comment: for more advanced options that require compability you also need android support library and repository from 'extras'.

Comment: what are sdk build tool? I need them?

Comment: yes, it is the library used to compile your program against the sdk, hence build tool.

Comment: but, i need to download all of them?

Comment: no, only the latest build tools and sdk are required, if you target and build against them. Compatibility is achieved by android itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare your desire version using this line

```
          <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

in manifest file. for more info check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

**EDIT**

you don't have to download anything for make strict versioning.

**android:minSdkVersion**
Like the name suggests, defines the minimum API level your application works on. This is used by Play Store to detect if the application is compatible with the users device. So, if your minSdkVersion is 7, Play Storewill show the application to devices from API level 7 (2.1) and up. This attribute should be set by all apps!

**android:maxSdkVersion**
This defines the maximum API level your application works on. Again, Play Store uses this to detect if an application is compatible with a device. Please note, that there in most cases is no reason to use this! it is perfectly possible to create a single APK which works on every API level from your minSdkVersion and up!

**android:targetSdkVersion**
Unlike the other two attributes, this is used by the Android platform itself. This attribute should be set to the maximum API level you tested your application on. If not set, this will default to your minSdkVersion.

you can also visit this to get more details http://simonvt.net/2012/02/07/what-api-level-should-i-target/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to download all Android SDK, just get `Android 3.0` (**API 11**) and `Android 5.0` (**API 21)** and declare the min and max `targetsdk` in the `manifest` file.

Comment: Only with this 2 downloads the app will work on api 19 for example?